# fatal: Not a git repository: /Users/Mathias/Projects/punycode.js/.git/modules/vendor/docdown

Tags: git

[image]

I got "fatal: Not a git repository" when performing git add node_modules, which is a node module directory.

it looks like one of the modules triggers this msg:

"/Users/Mathias/Projects/punycode.js/.git/modules/vendor/docdown"

I searched all "fatal: Not a git repository" on stackoverflow and tried the "git init" approach. It doesn't work in my situation.

Can you help?

Comment: Does that folder have a submodule in it?

Comment: Where are you in the file system in relation to that folder, "/Users/Mathias/Projects/punycode.js/.git/modules/vendor/docdown"? Where is the project/repository located?

Comment: my project git root is at: /Users/tom/documents/projects/bbvs. "/Users/Mathias/Projects/punycode.js/.git/modules/vendor/docdown" doesn't exist on my computer. Did I answer your question?

Comment: to @Leigh, I can't locate /Users/Mathias/Projects/punycode.js/.git/modules/vendor/docdown on my computer.

Comment: Is it because my folder is too deep that is over git's limit?

Answer (score 6):

If you already have a package.json file, create a .gitignore file in the root of your repo with this line in it:

```
node_modules/
```

There's really no need to commit node_modules since someone else can run `npm install` and get the same dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to setup a CI process using CruiseControl.Net. I eventually found that running the following, was enough to cure the error.

```
npm install punycode
```

This allowed the build to proceed, however fell over again when Cruise Control was running "git clean -f -d -x". This was due to the really deep network of folders installed in node_modules - file names too long for windows to cope!

For the time being, I switched of the clean with

```
<cleanUntrackedFiles>false</cleanUntrackedFiles>
```

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Are you using url  "0.7.9" as dependency just like me? What I had to do to get rid of this problem was just update url version to "0.10.1" in my package.json.

The issue is explained here.
 [Bump url dependency 0.7.9 -> 0.10.1 #10](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/pull/10)

Thanks.